# Where can I find a driver for my plantronic Intertek 81242 headset for Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, headset, bluetooth-3.0

I'm on a Windows 7 machine and the headset doesn't automatically load when the USB is plugged in. I couldn't find the driver on plantronic's website.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I find that when USB devices start acting funny I like to clean things up. I check to see how many USB ghosted devices exist and remove them. So try this, unplug your headset and follow the instructions from this [link](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/504/how-to-uninstall-hidden-devices-drivers-and-services/).

If the device didn't come with drivers, then you probably don't need to have them to work. Most reputable companies include drivers for their stuff if needed.